# cuda filter with ouput of this block is the input of the next block

Tags: gpu, cuda

Working on a filter following, I am having a problem of doing these pieces of codes for processing an image in GPU:

```
for(int h=0; h<height; h++) {
    for(int w=1; w<width; w++) {
    image[h][w] = (1-a)*image[h][w] + a*image[h][w-1];
    }
}
```

If I define:

> dim3 threads_perblock(32, 32)

then each block I have: 32 threads can be communicated. The threads of this block can not communicate with the threads from other blocks.

Within a thread_block, I can translate that pieces of code using shared_memory however, for edge (I would say): image[0,31] and image[0,32] in different threadblocks. The image[0,31] should get value from image[0,32] to calculate its value. But they are in different threadblocks.

so that is the problem.

How would I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use the same buffer for read and write? If a=1 then you are moving data one column right. Is that what you want compute?

Comment: that is the sample code in CPU, read and write should be different in GPU. for waiting is simple because it is not parallel communication any more, any other idea? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `image` is in global memory then there is no problem - you don't need to use shared memory and you can just access pixels directly from `image` without any problem.

However if you have already done some processing prior to this, and a block of `image` is already in shared memory, then you have a problem, since you need to do neighbourhood operations which are outside the range of your block. You can do one of the following - either:

- write shared memory back to global memory so that it is accessible to neighbouring blocks (disadvantage: performance, synchronization between blocks can be tricky)

or:

- process additional edge pixels per block with an overlap (1 pixel in this case) so that you have additional pixels in each block to handle the edge cases, e.g. work with a 34x34 block size but store only the 32x32 central output pixels (disadvantage: requires additional logic within kernel, branches may result in warp divergence, not all threads in block are fully used)

Unfortunately neighbourhood operations can be really tricky in CUDA and there is always a down-side whatever method you use to handle edge cases.

Comment: Hi @Paul. thanks for your answer. However, I think both of your proposed ways dont address to giving a solution yet. I am searching more about it

Comment: if it is global memory, a thread at position 32 wants to address the thread in position 31. but it it not possible. so you can not do with global memory I think. Without using share_memory, there is no order of reading the value from the image

Comment: @devn: no, for *global* memory any thread can access any global memory location - only *shared* memory is private to a given block of threads

Comment: yes, that is correct. but what i mean is for global memory: if a[32] = [a32] - 1, a[32] is in block 2, a[31] is in block 1, we dont know when the a[32] is changed so a[31] can not start... something is hardly to explain...

Comment: @devn: yes, as I said in my answer, synchronization can be tricky between blocks, but it's not impossible. However your algorithm is particularly nasty in that it seems to have dependencies which will be very hard to deal with in any kind of parallel programming model.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a busy spin (no joke). Just make the thread processing a[32] execute:

```
while(!variable);
```

before starting to compute and the thread processing a[31] do

```
variable = 1;
```

when it finishes. It's up to you to generalize this. I know this is considered "rogue programming" in CUDA, but it seems the only way to achieve what you want. I had a very similar problem and it worked for me. Your performance might suffer though...
Be careful however, that

```
dim3 threads_perblock(32, 32)
```

means you have 32 x 32 = 1024 threads per block.